# Compressing and cooling air in a Coolgardie Safe, then decompressing

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, condensed-matter, energy-conservation, temperature

If I put container of compressed air into a Coolgardie Safe, and brought the temperature down by say 3°C, how am I supposed to calculate the temperature of the air after it is decompressed back to ambient air pressure?

I'm not asking for calculations, I'm asking for formulae and theories which I can use here.

Comment: What ae your thoughts on this so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before putting the container into the safe, it has a pressure $P_0$ and a volume $V$, and it's at room temperature $T_{room}$. After it's been cooled, its volume is the same, but its pressure and temperature have changed. You know that its temperature is changed to $T_{cool}$, and you need to compute its pressure after cooling $P_{cool}$. Since this is a constant-volume process, you can use the Gay-Lussac law:

$$\frac{P_0}{T_{room}}=\frac{P_{cool}}{T_{cool}}$$

After decompression, its volume increases to some volume and temperature $V_{final}$ and $T_{final}$, and its pressure decreases to $P_{ambient}$. The pressure, volume, and temperature are all changing, which means that where each quantity eventually ends up depends on ***how*** the air is decompressed.

If we can assume that the can of compressed air is decompressed quickly enough that there isn't time for it to transfer heat to the surroundings, then it can be approximated as an *adiabatic* process. In an adiabatic process, we have that

$$P_{cool}V^\gamma = P_{ambient}V_{final}^\gamma$$

where $\gamma$ is a constant that depends on the number of thermodynamic degrees of freedom of the gas. For dry air, we have that $\gamma\approx 7/5$. We also have the combined gas law, which relates the pressure, temperature, and volume of a gas before and after those quantities change:

$$\frac{P_{cool}V}{T_{cool}}=\frac{P_{ambient}V_{final}}{T_{final}}$$

Combining these two equations, we get that:

$$T_{final} = T_{cool}\left(\frac{V_{final}}{V}\right)\left(\frac{P_{ambient}}{P_{cool}}\right)=T_{cool}\left(\frac{P_{ambient}}{P_{cool}}\right)^{2/7}$$

Comment: What happens if the can is decompressed slowly. Because I think that's the whole point. I want to make the air become cooler as it is decompressed and I guess that's only possible if it loses heat to the surroundings?

Comment: @ElFlea The decompressed air will be coldest if it decompresses quickly. Slowing the decompression will make the decompressed air warmer. If you do the decompression extremely slowly, then the air will be at room temperature once decompressed, since it has enough time to come to equilibrium with the (comparatively warm) surrounding air as it decompresses.

Comment: How did the final equation have an exponent of 2/7? I'm a 10th grader so it would help to explain how $$T_{cool}\left(\frac{V_{final}}{V}\right)\left(\frac{P_{ambient}}{P_{cool}}\right)$$ became $$T_{cool}\left(\frac{P_{ambient}}{P_{cool}}\right)^{2/7}$$

Comment: @ElFlea Using the adiabatic relation between $P$ and $V$ before and after expansion, you can find an expression for $V_{final}/V$ and substitute it into the last equation.

Comment: So basically if I just used $$Vfinal/V$$, I wouldn't have to bother using the 2/7, right?