# How did the adiabatic process equations combine to form this new one?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, condensed-matter, energy-conservation, temperature

[Compressing and cooling air in a Coolgardie Safe, then decompressing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/552250/compressing-and-cooling-air-in-a-coolgardie-safe-then-decompressing/552275?noredirect=1#comment1246830_552275)

I'm a 10th grader so it would help to explain how, in the answer to the link above, $$T_{cool}\left(\frac{V_{final}}{V}\right)\left(\frac{P_{ambient}}{P_{cool}}\right)$$ became... $$T_{cool}\left(\frac{P_{ambient}}{P_{cool}}\right)^{2/7}$$

Where did 2/7 come from?

Comment: The 2/7 comes from analyzing the process of adiabatic reversible expansion or compression of an ideal gas.  It is related to the ratio of the heat capacity at constant pressure to the heat capacity at constant volume.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the 7/5 gamma value?

Comment: Yes it does.  $$1-1/\gamma$$

Comment: If you use $T_{cool}\left(\frac{V_{final}}{V}\right)\left(\frac{P_{ambient}}{P_{cool}}\right)$ with input values, it doesn't give the same answer as $T_{cool}\left(\frac{P_{ambient}}{P_{cool}}\right)^{2/7}$. There's contradiction here?!